# How to pass from an interface to other in Android

Tags: android, interface

I'm a beginner in Android.
I created two interfaces with DroiDraw, then I added them **res/layout/a.xml** and **res/layout/b.xml**

My goal is passing from interface **a** to **b**.

How can I do??

Comment: By "passing" do you mean "navigating" or "passing data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data from Activity A to ActivityB, then add it to the Intent that starts Activity B

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(i);
```

Also have a look at the Bundle class.

Answer (score 1):

If passing means "passing data" - look into SharedPreferences or Sqlite - it depends upon your options
If Passing means "navigating" - associate an activity with interface b - so launch activity b when the user wants to navigate to it from interface a.

Comment: If it is only about passing data from one activity to the other, storing data into Prefs or Sqlite is overdone (IMO). Of course this fits well, if the data needs persistence.